# Items in second level in itemize not transparent

Tags: beamer, itemize

my goal is to make only the items in the first level transparent. How do i do that. I have following code, but it does also grey out the items in the second level

```
\documentclass[
]{beamer}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item test1
        \item if this item is shown
        \begin{itemize}
            \item then this subitem should be shown also, and not in the next step
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have edited the code, here its not grey out, but it is the same problem. if the second item appears, then i want the sub-item appear with it, and not in the next step.

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Should the second level items already be non-transparent when their parent item is still grey?

Comment: If the parent is still grey, then the second level items should be still grey. but if the parent item is active (not grey) then the second level item should be active too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can undo the piecewise uncovering by using `[<.->]` for your second level list:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item test1
        \item if this item is shown
        \begin{itemize}[<.->]
            \item then this subitem should be shown also, and not in the next step
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i was not aware that is possible undo piecewise uncovering. thank you! (+1)